# Access HTML page hosted on different server using NodeJS

Tags: html, node.js, server, hosting

**Brief :**

I have a static HTML/JS/CSS website hosted on a server called **A**. (I have access to it.)
And I have NodeJS server running on server **B**. Now I want to apply the Authentication mechanism using **PassportJS Local strategy**.

**Questions :**

- Is it possible to apply authentication using this way?
- What are the ways that I can show an HTML page from the server **A** when the request is made on the NodeJS server?

Any advice/information/help is awesome.

Thanks in advance.